# For a manual EBS snapshot, how do set the retention policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm taking a manual backup of an EBS volume. I'd like to keep this snapshot around for a while, how do I set the retention so it does not get archived?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Amazon EBS Snapshots will remain until you specifically delete them.

If you wish, you can [Automate snapshot lifecycles - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-ami-policy.html) to have the snapshot automatically deleted after a period of time.